# event listeners ever multiplying fires in CreateJS / Animate CC in the HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, animate-cc

Animate CC, HTML5 Canvas. I have an animation with several clickthrough exits, to twitter, facebook etc. The animation has a repeat button. On the first play-through when I click the twitter exit just one twitter page opens, on the 2nd play through I click the same exit button and it opens TWO twitter pages, (and so on ad-infinitum. If I clicked repeat 50 times if would open 50 twitter pages :) ).

Here's one code snippet from frame 342:

```
root.twBtn.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseOverHandler_2.bind(this));

var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);

function fl_MouseOverHandler_2(){
    window.open(clickTag1, "_blank");
}
```

I tried removing the event listener (in the replay function) on that same frame, and I'm still getting the same thing happening, this +1 of windows opening each time clicktag1 etc is fired after replaying the ad. How can I fix this? I'm not sure if the event listener is actually being removed, or what is happening.

```
// Replay
root.reBtn.on("click", function(evt){
    root.twBtn.removeEventListener("click", fl_MouseOverHandler_2);
    root.gotoAndPlay("start");
});
```

Basically my listeners are firing +1 times each time I replay the animation. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681569/animate-html5-canvas-event-listeners-firing-more-than-once) and it didn't work in my situation. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.

I added `root.x = 1;` on Animate CC Frame 1 `(createjs's frame 0)`, the banner replays from  Animate CC Frame 2 `(createjs's frame 1)` (so it never plays the frame `root.x` is originally defined in again), and I switched out the eventlistener code for the following, wrapped in an `if` statement testing `root.x`. It works for me.

```
if (root.x === 1){
root.twBtn.on("click", function(evt){
    window.open(clickTag1, "_blank");
    y=y+1;  
    })
};
```